# Google Fit recording stopped working suddenly

Tags: android, google-fit

In my app I am recording a datatype **TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA** and reading **TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA** using history API. It was working perfect for me and I have released the app to play store also. Now I am noticing that recording is not working with this datatype. I don’t know what happened suddenly . Then I tried  recording datatype **TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT** and reading **TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT** using history API. I can see that in Samsung S6 it working fine. But on Samsung S3 it's not working. I want to record user activities like running walking and read that data. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried testing your app with [different devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html)? also, please include device specification.

Comment: Does it start working again if the user logs into Google Fit on their device? I am seeing something similar when we try to track the steps data.